# How to use vba to push excel spreadsheet range content to a specific form within a URL

Tags: excel, vba

I have been researching many different forums, YouTubing like crazy, and have found things that I suspect are close, but I haven't been able to get the desired effect i am looking for.  I am fairly confident that I know the steps required to carry out a particular process, but am seeking the help of anyone willing to lend a hand.

**Intent (why this might be also useful to you):**

I am in charge of scheduling site visits (for my boss) to many different real estate properties.  Each property has a different lead contact that changes periodically.  I have been working to create a spreadsheet that:

- Keeps tabs on which step in the scheduling process each client is at,
  at any given time
- Provides an intuitive platform for keeping the most up to date contact
  information, meeting time, and miscellaneous notes for each client when they are called to schedule an appointment
- Connects and color codes (in Google Maps via BatchGeo.com) the data
  from the previous two bullet points, to properties on a map.

**Case example of how this would be useful**
By visualizing this data on a map, and creating groups (denoted by different color google map pins), one can intuitively look at a map and schedule consecutive appointments for sites that are within certain proximity of eachother to "kill two birds with one stone."

**How this process would be done manually:**

I want to automate the process of navigating to a previously created URL (the edit map link), copy & pasting all of the cells within a given cell range (IE. A1:E10) to a particular form with that "edit map link", and clicking the update button. Furthermore, all navigation should be done within Excel (no need to open up a separate browser) by using an embedded web browser.

//Batch Geo "edt map" link

//http://batchgeo.com/map/edit/?map_id=2874687&d=0aa639559d0883376a15e66afdc042b0
//Website source code printscreen
http://printscreen.me/snaps/d906d04b89b98d54b4bfa6fd174e911cd08e8a1f

**Draft of Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    WebBrowser2.Navigate2 ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Value

    WebBrowser2.Document.getElementById("edit_form").Range.("B3:I7").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: //Corresponding example Excel file printscreen
*http://printscreen.me/snaps/3331afc90194a5759740884ef650fcb16dccce6c
//Link to actual excel file
*https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/108616020/TestBatchGeoMap1.xlsx

Comment: The `getElementById` method returns the element.  You might try something like:  `WebBrowser2.Document.getElementById("edit_form").Value = Range("B3:I7")` but I am not sure if this element is expecting to, or capable of receiving an *array* of values.

Comment: Just tested the above code, it does not work. The form is expecting a copy/paste operation or drag/drop I think...

Comment: Did you have a chance to test the answer I provided?  IF it works, please mark it as accepted...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IWebBrowser2 works like IE, this should do the trick.  I have tested this using IE since I am more familiar with that, but I think it should be the same.

**Note:** the first row in your range B3:I7 needs to contain the headers (Name, Phone Number, etc.) otherwise you will be prompted to validate the addresses, it will be much easier to just make sure your worksheet is formatted properly to send to the form.

```
Option Explicit
Sub LogMeIn()
'Requires reference to Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim htmlDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim el As HTMLFormElement
Dim pasteValues As String
Dim vals As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

'## Store the values in a delimited string
Set vals = Range("B3:I7")
For r = 1 To vals.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To vals.Columns.Count
        If Not c = 1 Then
            pasteValues = pasteValues & vbTab & vals(r, c)
        Else:
            pasteValues = pasteValues & vbNewLine & vals(r, c)
        End If

    Next
Next

'## Create an instance of IE (alternatively you can probably use WebBrowser2)
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

'## So you can see what's happening/debug. delete the next line if you want.
ie.Visible = True

'## Navigate to the URL:
ie.Navigate "http://batchgeo.com/map/edit/?map_id=2874687&d=0aa639559d0883376a15e66afdc042b0"

'## Make sure the page has finished loading
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'## Set our Document variable
Set htmlDoc = ie.Document

'## Set the element variable
Set el = htmlDoc.getElementById("sourceData")

'## Send the values to the form
el.innerText = pasteValues
'## I use this to confirm I have grabbed the correct element, you can delete or comment it out.
MsgBox "The form now contains the following data, although it may not be visible:" & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        pasteValues

'## Update the map
htmlDoc.getElementById("mapnow_button").Click

'## Cleanup
Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```